# Google Script: Issue deleting Specific Sheet in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Situation:

- I have a spreadsheet with 20 sheet.
- I have other script that copy sheets from other spreadsheet every days to this spreadsheet-
- I need to delete every days some specific sheet from a particular spreadsheet.

## Problem:

When the script ends to clear the sheets, the spreadsheet hangs and I have to exit and re-enter to the spreadsheet.

I'll appreciate if anyone can help to tunning this script to work without hangging the spreadsheet.

## Script:

```
    function shellDeleteSheets(){
     var sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4','Sheet5']; 
     for (var s in sheets){
     deleteSheetName(sheets[s]);
      }
    }

      function deleteSheetName(stname) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName(stname);
      if(!sh) {
        return;
      }
      ss.setActiveSheet(sh);
      ss.deleteActiveSheet();
      Utilities.sleep(400);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version I use without issue

```
function DeleteSheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3']; 
  var numberOfSheets = ss.getSheets().length;
  for(var s = numberOfSheets-1; s>0 ; s--){ // in my case I never delete the first sheet
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[s]);
    var shName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();

    if(sheets.indexOf(shName)>-1){
      var delSheet = ss.deleteActiveSheet();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);// send me back to first sheet
}
```

You could of course use the array of names as an argument for the function or  - that's what I do in some cases - give the names of the sheet I need to keep, in this case the if condition is just different .
the sleep can be 400 mS, not sure it makes any difference, I use 500 because at some time I found it more reliable... and I (try to) never change a working solution ;-)

---

**EDIT following your comment :**

to make active the sheet called 'Updated' just change the last line of the code like this :

```
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Updated'));
```

please note also that I moved this line in the original code, outside of the loop, sorry for this small error ^^

Comment: Thanks Serge for your quickly update but this script is getting this error "(class)(class)setActiveSheet((class))". I think because me sheets the ID increase every time when I use the CopySheet script. I needs to know name for delete the sheet. 
Why I copy sheet and not copy row, because I don't know who to copy row from Sheet 1 to Sheet 1 to other spreadsheet. That Why I implement two script one for delete all sheet with a specific name and other that copy from Spreadsheet A to B.

Comment: Serge:

- Your script work but not delete the first sheet as per your update. 
- Your script delete the sheet very fast but I have an issue the fist sheet is the "sheet1" and when the script end and try to set the sheet 0 as active it's the same that I needs to delete.

Meaby if you can help to set as active the sheet called "Updated", I think that will fix the issue with hangging.

Comment: see edit, and change the code with the new updated version, there was a small error that didn't prevent it to work but it's better like that.

Comment: Serge: your script return to Sheet Called "Updated" but is not deleting the 1st sheet.

Comment: Serge: I change 

    for(var s = numberOfSheets-1; s>=0 ; s--)

I Think is not the correct way because in this case maybe delete all sheet >=0. When I run it work but delete some other sheet Ex.Sheet10, I logout and loggin and that sheet appear again the sheet10.

Comment: In the menu on the spreadsheet the process never finish when detele sheets and set "Update" sheet as active in the menu bar still appear "processing"...

Comment: please ensure you use exactly the code as shown above, it deletes ONLY the sheets that are listed in the names array. If you continue to have issue feel free to share a test spreadsheet to show the issue you have.

Comment: Hi Serge, sorry for dalay... I'm working a lot... I want the script just delete a specific sheet without hanging the spreadsheet. Here you have the spreadsheet [SOURCE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqPVRE_7emo-dHduUURENnVrS1haWkdYSFk2RUw2REE) & [TARGET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqPVRE_7emo-dElIbDQxMTEzMF95ZjMxTnpYMXR2RUE), the lastone have the script to delete sheet and copy sheet.  Just I want to delete an specific sheet without hangging the spreadsheet. I'll appreciate your help